# how to print a string containing both single and double quote in php

Tags: php

I have have string  in php as follows:

shows that he/she is a firm believer in “If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it” or “leave well enough alone”

when I print this string it output something like this:

shows that he/she is a firm believer in â€œIf it ainâ€™t broke, donâ€™t fix itâ€ or â€œleave well enough aloneâ€

How can i print this exactly as the first one? is there any solution?

Comment: put your code please

Comment: <?php 
$text = mysql_real_escape_string('shows that he/she is a firm believer in “If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it” or “leave well enough alone”');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($text);
exit;
?>

Comment: This has nothing to do with quotes, it has to do with encodings. Your "quotes" are not plain standard `'` characters, they're fancier Unicode quotes. You need to learn how to handle encodings correctly. Start here: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your source code file uses the same charset as the browser interpreting your file. For example if you store your source code as `utf-8`, be sure to tell the browser to use `utf-8` too:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

If the text comes from a database or a file, ensure the table/file uses the same charset too.

Answer (score -1):

try with,

```
print_r(utf8_encode($text));
```

Comment: It works fine in this case.
But what to do if the same text we are importing from excel file?